# Sound comes from the app when it is paused

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have problems with my app because multimedia sound is heard when the app is in background

I have defined my Media player like this;

```
private void playLocalAudio(int R1)throws Exception
{
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R1);  
mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

For calling PlayLocalAudio I do:

```
try{
    playLocalAudio(R.raw.fartw1);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}});
```

But I am not able to call correctly MediaPlayer.Stop()

I am trying:

```
public void onPause()
{
 super.onPause();
 mediaplayer.stop();
}
```

But it doesn't work. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your code has a class variable mediaPlayer that's not visible in your example. In that case you have variable shadowing, because you're instantiating a new mediaPlayer in playLocalAudio and that instance is not visible inside the pause method. So stop is never called. Remove the MediaPlayer class name from the declaration in playLocalAudio.

Comment: +1 for correct answer as I see it, yet an example will make it more clear.

Comment: No, I have no other definitions of mediaPlayer

Comment: The variable mediaPlayer is method local.  If you don't have another declaration of mediaplayer, then mediaplayer.stop() doesn't compile.  I''m assuming that the difference between P and p is a typo?